# Adding another select statement to a LEFT JOIN select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  jobs
  LEFT JOIN bids
    ON jobs.userID = bids.jobID
WHERE
  bids.bidder = '$userName'
```

But this statement does only show the results from the "jobs" table. I also want to show results from the "bids" table, for example the column "bids" from the table bids.

How do I combine that in the above select statement?

Comment: What is the structure of the tables `jobs` and `bids`? What is the definition of the foreign key between the two tables? What does 'show the results' mean? The `*` shows all columns from the tables listed in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: You should see the results of the two tables with your current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` in Select * From... shows only the columns from your From-line. If you wanna Columns from your join-table, you have to add the column like this: bids.. if you use a alias (b and j in my example) it is easier to reading the statement... you also can use a "wildcard" in your select statement for your jointables.. like this bids.* (b.*)

in your case you need this:

```
   SELECT j.*, b.* 
     FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN bids b
       ON j.userID=b.jobID 
    WHERE b.bidder = '$userName'
```

Comment: @EdiG. Can you please send a link to us about this behaviour of the MySQL or PHP?

Comment: @Pred this is only MySql(Sql)-Symtax i hope it will help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html

Comment: I know the `JOIN` syntax. The linked page does not mention that you have to use aliases for the joined tables. I know that your answer solved the OP's problem, but the explanation is a bit insufficient. At the end of the linked page (before the comments), the examples are using `*` in the `SELECT` clause and there are no aliases.